# charts_flutter reduce padding bettween bars

Tags: flutter, charts

I've searched all the examples on the pub.dev page for charts_flutter, but I can't seem to figure out how to reduce the spacing between bars. I have 12 bars and on smaller phones this breaks the label into 4 because the label only uses the space the bar bellow it has used.
is there a way to either make the label use the blank space, or reduce the padding between bars so that the label has more space?

ps. this is a stacked bar ( barGroupingType: BarGroupingType.stacked,)

[image]

on a second note, i'm also trying to figure out how to render the grey line to the start and end of first and last bars. instead of to the center.

Answer (score 0):

Setting barGroupingType to BarGroupingType.grouped and lowering the groupingWidthFraction property's value will result in fewer spaces between bars. Each group of bars' width is established by this attribute as a percentage of the available space. To narrow the space between bars, you might set it to 0.8.

For EG:

```
BarChart(
  [
    ....
  ],
  animate: true,
  barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.grouped,
  groupingWidthFraction: 0.8,
);
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan, i added a visual aid, i need stacked bars 
also, couldnt find a groupingwithfraction property